# How to publish lang labels of custom package?

Tags: laravel

Making custom package in Laravel 9 app by https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/packages docs
my lang labels are not found. I think I need to publish them , but not sure which is valid format?

in definition of the packe :

```
class MyPackageProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        \Log::info(varDump(-1, ' -1 MyPackageProvider boot::'));
        $this->loadRoutesFrom(__DIR__.'/../routes/web.php');

        $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__ . '/../views', 'MyPackage' );
        $this->loadMigrationsFrom(__DIR__.'/../database/migrations');

        $this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__.'/../lang', 'MyPackage');
        $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/../lang' => $this->app->langPath('vendor/MyPackage'),
        ]);
```

I got error on command :

```
php artisan vendor:publish --lang=vendorname\MyPackage
The "--lang" option does not exist.
```

Which command is valid ?

**Details Info:**

On command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lang --
```

I got error:

```
No publishable resources for tag [lang].
```

Have I to definetag somehow ?

Have I to define in MyPackageProvider my additive options ?

Details Info # 2:

With additive option "'lang'" in publishes(which I missed)

```
public function boot()
{
    ...
    $this->publishes([
        __DIR__.'/../lang' => $this->app->langPath('vendorname/MyPackage'),
    ], 'lang');
```

Running command with output:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lang

   INFO  Publishing [lang] assets.

  Copying directory [packages/vendorname/MyPackage/src/lang] to [lang/vendorname/MyPackage] ............................................. DONE
```

I found my lang files copied into /lang/vendorname/MyPackage/en subdirectory...
I expected they would be located under "/lang/" subdirectory...
I think that is not correct?

I use my labels as

```
__('botman.You have to answer to :quizzesCount questions',
```

Or must I remade a path like :

```
__('vendorname.MyPackage.botman.You have to answer to :quizzesCount questions',
```

where "botman.php" is my file inside of "/lang/en" subdirectory...
?

Thank you!

Comment: Running `php artisan help vendor:publish` didn't help?

Comment: this command shows help text only... But to publish langs of my package ?\

Comment: Run `php artisan vendor:publish` and select your package provider. https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/packages#publishing-language-files

Comment: That is my question : I did not find valid format of command like vendor:publish MyPackage--lang

Comment: php artisan vendor:publish --tag=lang --provider=Vendor\MyPackage\MyPackageProvider

Comment: Please look at Details Info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the tag in your code like this:

```
 $this->publishes([
            __DIR__.'/../lang' => $this->app->langPath('vendor/MyPackage'),
        ], 'lang');
```

[Laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/packages#publishing-file-groups)

Edit :

To be able to use the lang helper `__()`, you must pay attention about the vendorname you define.

So if you load the views like this :

```
$this->loadTranslationsFrom(__DIR__.'/../lang', 'MyPackage');
```

Your vendorname is MyPackage and so you have to use the lang helper like this :

```
__('MyPackage::any.translation')
```

After that, if you publish the files, you will find  a subfolder `vendor` in your lang directory and inside it a subfolder `MyPackage`, this is the way to do it as Laravel will load the translations from there. But it is not mandatory to publish them, if not published, Laravel will use the files in the package directory.

Comment: Please look at Details Info # 2

Comment: I updated my answer with more details